# Internal Ids generated on Netsuite custom records not sequential

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have created two custom record types in Netsuite, for one of the record types when I am inserting new records via script I am seeing the internal ids are `1, 101, 201, 301` etc instead of `1,2,3,4`.
While on the other custom record its as expected. Is it something wrong on the custom record creation or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

No. Internal ID's can be created differently when done in batches, deleted, or because it's a day that ends in "y". It's standard behavior. Rest easy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I didn't perform any batch operation, it was simple record.create, record.setvalue and record.save from script inside a for loop. The loop had only one item when I tested.
I couldn't understand what you mean by a day ending in "y". Don't all the days end in "y"?

Answer (score 0):

On the Custom Record itself check the "Numbering" tab.  Reference [Suite Answer Id: 10146](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10146/kw/10146).  Check the **Enable** box to turn on automatic numbering.  Check the **Allow Override** box if you want to be able to enter a custom number.  Check the **Update** box to number record instances that have already been created.